# implementing referntial integrity with php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, referential-integrity

i have three tabs in my Db:

```
1.pers_info(id(primary), name ,....)
2.contacts(c_id(primary), phone, email, ...)
```

now 1 person can have multiple rows in contacts tab.
thus to minimize redundancy i made another tab `contact_relation(id (foregin key references pers_info(id), c_id (foregin key references contacts(c_id))`

i successfully created the relation and also was able to insert apt entries(related `id` and `c_id`) to it "using `last_insert_id();`" to extract `id` and `c_id` required.

now the problem..

i dropped tab `contacts_rel`. and created it this way :

```
CREATE TABLE contacts_relation (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    cid INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES pers_info(id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
      REFERENCES contacts(c_id)
);
```

if now i try to insert into tab `cont_rel`, it gives error : 
cannot add or update a child row foreign key constraint fails.
which makes sense..

i was hoping that adding constraints in the defn of tab cont_rel would save the hassle of inserting entries in it manually using "`last_insert_id();`"

> so is there a way, i could maintain ref integrity with new data
>   coming.. thanks.

Comment: Why the third table? When you many to many relation you need intermediate table. You have one to many relation so two tables are sufficient. Or am I missing something? (Table `contacts` need FK to table `pers_info`. Add it if you don't have already. It doesn's show up in your compact table info.)

Comment: i agree @ZZ-bb, thanks for ur comment, but even following ur way would i be able to insert into table contacts(having c_id as FK , referencing id of pers_info.. wont it sill give the same error : "cannot add or update a child row foreign key constraint fails"..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you but no. You add (inside transaction) first to the mother table (`pers_info`) and the add to the child table (`contancts`). You use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to add the FK to the child table (if you add to two tables at the same time). You can also add only to the child table but you need to know the `id` of the person from the mother table.

Comment: BTW: you can also allow your FK to be null but that's kind of silly thing to do since you won't be able to connect that contact info to any person. But at least you won't get errors. But this is why errors are a good thing. If your FK constraint fail, it's good to know about it.

Comment: Transaction is explained for example here (just a simple example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043887/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables/10044742#10044742

Comment: following ur seggestion i tried :                                                                  ALTER TABLE contacts
ADD FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
REFERENCES pers_info(id);                                                                                                but it gave error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`family`.`#sql-12bc_5d`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-12bc_5d_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `pers_info` (`id`))

Comment: Check your syntax. You `ADD CONSTRAINT`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: @ZZ-bb can you post an answer so that i can accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the third table? When you many to many relation you need intermediate table. You have one to many relation so two tables are sufficient. Table contacts need FK to table `pers_info`. Add it if you don't have already.

Here's a simple transaction example with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`: [SQL INSERT INTO multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043887/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables/10044742#10044742)

Some info about foreign keys and altering table:

- [Add Foreign Key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table)
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html